# Threads synchronize for Ipcameras in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, ip-camera

I hope someone can help me. I am working in a C++ application on Linux in which I am using threads, and IpCameras.

This is my main.cpp code:

```
int main(){

cv::VideoCapture cap("rtsp://admin:admin@X.X.x.X/0/video1");
cv::VideoCapture cap2("rtsp://admin:admin@X.X.X.x/0/video1");
cv::VideoCapture cap3("rtsp://admin:admin@X.X.X.X/0/video1");
cv::VideoCapture cap4("rtsp://admin:admin@X.X.X.X/0/video1");

While(1)
{

   switch(value)
   {

case a:

  pthread_detach(t1);
  cvDestroyAllWindows();
  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &video1, NULL);
  break;

case b:

  pthread_detach(t1);
  cvDestroyAllWindows();
  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &video2, NULL);
  break;

case c:

  pthread_detach(t1);
  cvDestroyAllWindows();
  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &video3, NULL);
  break;

case d:

  pthread_detach(t1);
  cvDestroyAllWindows();
  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &video4, NULL);
  break;

   }
}
}
```

Here is the code of video1, video2, video3 and video4 :

```
extern int v1;

extern cv::VideoCapture cap ;


void* videoFrontConfiguration(void*) {


Display* disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Screen*  scrn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(disp);
int height = scrn->height;
int width  = scrn->width;

//Frame declaration
            cv::Mat frame;

            //Create window for the ip cam video
              cv::namedWindow("Front", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);



              cvSetWindowProperty( "Front", CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN );



               //Position of the screen where the video is shows
               cvMoveWindow("Front", 0, 0);
            cvResizeWindow( "Front", width, height );

            //while we keep connected to the ip camera, we process the frames we receive
            while ( cap.isOpened())
            {
                //we get the frame from the ip camera
                cap.read(frame);

                //if the frame is empty we break
                if(frame.empty()) break;

                //we show the video frame in "video" window
                cv::imshow("Front", frame);

                if(v1 == 1){
                    v1 = 0;


                    pthread_exit(NULL);
                }

                //To close the window
                if(cv::waitKey(20) >= 0) break;

            }

}
```

The thing is that I am working with RTSP cameras, so it is as live broadcast, but when I try to run the application and start to show the cameras after few seconds is appear this errors:

```
    [1;31m[h264 @ 0x1d430] out of range intra chroma pred mode at 20 9
    [0m[1;31m[h264 @ 0x1d430] error while decoding MB 20 9              
    [0m[1;31m[h264 @ 0x1d430] P sub_mb_type 5 out of range at 2 12
    [0m[1;31m[h264 @ 0x1d430] error while decoding MB 2 12
    [0m[1;31m[h264 @ 0x1f0b0] out of range intra chroma pred mode at 11 1
    [0m[1;31m[h264 @ 0x1f0b0] error while decoding MB 11 1
```

So what I believe is that as I am doing the capture in the main thread like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("rtsp://admin:admin@X.X.x.X/0/video1");
```

and then I render the video in the other thread, maybe that could be a problem of syncronhized. But to be honest I am not sure, because I do not have to much experience with the IpCameras.

So please if someone have some idea for make a propertly syncornhized or if it is other problem please let me know.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You are creating four instances of cv::VideoCapture cap, cap1, cap2, cap3 but in the video threads you are only using cap variable. So if I am not wrong four simultaneous threads will read from same cv::VideoCapture instance. If that is the case try to pass the cv::VideoCapture object as an argument to the pthread_create function (i.e. last argument).